# This 'else if' condition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck in a simple `else if` condition and believe it's the first time I got an issue with this. Maybe I did something wrong, I don't know.

```js
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() >= '250') {
        alert('red');
    } else if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
        alert('blink');
    } else {
        alert('nothing');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="lblShowCounter">800</span>
```

The problem is this code only executes first `if` not `else if` looks like it won't check the element text twice, right? But when I use this it works fine:

```js
    $('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() >= '250') {
            alert('red');
        }
    });

    $('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
            alert('blink');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="lblShowCounter">800</span>
```

Note that I want two alerts, because 800 is greater than 300 and also greater than 250.

Comment: Change the order around because 300 is greater that 250

Comment: @jeff you mean [This](https://jsfiddle.net/48whpajb/) ? or tried before but not working

Comment: An if statement will stop after the first "match". Any number that is > 300 will also be > 250, so it won't ever hit the second condition.

Comment: @pedram - works as advertised :-)

Comment: Noting you amendment - then do not use an else/if statement because you want every condition checked and acted upon accordingly.

Comment: Thanks now I figured out @jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question has since been updated to indicate you want 2 alerts.

With an `if/elseif` block, the block will complete once it hits the first match. So in your code, once it matches `250` the if statement completes and the `elseif` is never evaluated.

To get multiple conditions to execute independently, they should be multiple if statements:

```
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text(),
        matched;

    if (text >= '300') {
        alert('blink');
        matched = true;
    }
    if (text >= '250') {
        alert('red');
        matched = true;
    }

    if (!matched) {
        alert('nothing');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, So I shouldn't use `else if` in this case.. looks like I should follow second example in my question with a one `each`, thanks for explanation.

Comment: Well maybe, it depends on what your use case is. If you want  to test the absence of a match as well then using multiple loops won't be that useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your if/else statements are in the wrong order. It should be:

```js
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
        alert('black');
    } else if ($(this).text() >= '250') {
        alert('blink');
    } else {
    alert('nothing');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="lblShowCounter">800</span>
```

300 is greater than 250, so the second statement will never be executed, since for all values greater than 250 (including greater 300), the first statement is true.

If you want both statements to be executed, then you should not use `else if`, because that stops execution in case the first statement is true. Instead use two `if` clauses, i.e. like:

```
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
        alert('black');
    }
    if ($(this).text() >= '250') {
        alert('blink');
    }
});
```

Comment: 800 is greater than 300 and also greater than 250, right? now I should get two alert not one, alert is a sample, I want to use `addClass` later, I mean 800 is greater than 250 then addclass, and it's also greater than 300 so add another class.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Change the order around because 300 is greater that 250

```
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
        alert('blink');
    } else if ($(this).text() >= '250') {
        alert('red');
    } else {
    alert('nothing');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation of why you changed the statement order, the code just by itself doesn't indicate why it needs to be modified.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I originally placed this in the comments but thanks for the advice

Comment: 800 is greater than 300 and also greater than 250, right? now I should get two alert not one, alert is a sample, I want to use addClass later, I mean 800 is greater than 250 then addclass, and it's also greater than 300 so add another class.

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic of your code there is no condition where you will be able to hit the second if statement. You have to change the order around like this:

```
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
    alert('blink');
  } else if ($(this).text() >= '250') {
    alert('red');
  } else {
    alert('nothing');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `&&`, I mean limit the duration:

```
$('#lblShowCounter').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() >= '250' && $(this).text() < '300') {
        alert('red');
    } else if ($(this).text() >= '300') {
        alert('blink');
    } else {
    alert('nothing');
    }
});
```